# How to reset router on page refresh?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can I force navigation to the '/splash' route on page refresh?

If I find myself at '/discover' and I refresh the page it will remain there, however I'd prefer the application to start from the beginning again (/splash).

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/splash', pathMatch: 'full' },   
  { path: 'splash'             , component: SplashComponent        },
  { path: 'discover'           , component: DiscoverComponent      },
  { path: 'broadcast'          , component: BroadcastComponent     },
  { path: 'notifications'      , component: NotificationsComponent },
  { path: 'notifications/:key' , component: NotificationComponent  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

I've attempted to place a `router.navigate` call within my parent AppComponent's `OnInit` & `OnDestroy` methods, however it appears to be ignored.

```
ngOnInit( ) : void {
    this.router.navigate(['splash']); 
}
```

I've also attempted to place the navigate call within the `OnDestroy` method of the router itself.

Comment: What sort of webserver do you use? Apache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by subscribing to the first navigation event of the router in your `AppComponent` constructor:

```
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
    import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

    export class AppComponent {
      private subscription: any;

      constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.subscription = this.router.events
          .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart && e.id === 1)
          .subscribe(e => {
            this.redirectToSplash();
          });
      }

      private redirectToSplash() {
        this.router.navigate(["splash"]);
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
```